# Marvel Collect by Topps - Card Values?

Tags: mobile, marvel-collect

In the game "Marvel Collect by Topps" you collect cards of multiple rarities ect… and each time you collect a card, new or otherwise, you receive a small boost to your "Collection Score".  After scouring the internet I still do not know how much my rank should go up per card, per type.  So the question is:

**What are the Collection Score values of different card tiers? Does the set and tier separately affect the Collection Score?**

https://gyazo.com/720d34c88bb3dd24e20097d14b294d48

You can see this "rank" in the top center of the screen "615.52".  *This is not my account*

Cheers!! :)

**Compiling the List:**

Gray Base T1 - .05

Green Base T2 - .10

Red Base T3 - .20

Blue Base T4 - .40

Black Base T5 - In Progress

Purple Base T6 / Orange Base T6 / Common / Uncommon / Rare / Ect… - Unknown

I also still do not know if the set matters to the Collection Score. Once I get enough information, I will post it as an answer.